# Ускорить requests запрос

Tags: python, proxy, requests

```
r = request.get(url, proxies={"https": proxy}, headers={'Connection':'close'}
```

Можно ли ускорить запрос? Или скорость запроса зависит от скорости proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если говорить не об одном запросе, а о целой куче, то можно увеличить скорость получения ответа от сервера (суммарно) путем изменения библиотеки request(синхронной) на какую нибудь асинхронную библиотеку, например Async + Aiohttp

Answer (score 0):

В основном библиотеки реализованы на основе протокола HTTP, и ускорить его работу можно только путем сжатия передаваемых данных. Скорость работы на прямую зависит от "скорости" вашего соединения с конечным сервером.